# Соединение atmega328 и esp8266 по I2C

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Хочу сделать Wi-Fi сигнализацию из Atmega328 и ESP8266, с отправкой смс на телеграмм бота.

Чтобы избежать кучи лишней работы с согласованием уровней, хотелось бы узнать можно ли запитать оба девайса от 3.3в и соединить оба МК по UART?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350250/i2c-communication-between-atmega328p-and-esp8266ex-can-only-send-8-bytes-bug

Answer (score 0):

Нет, ATmega328 - это 5-вольтовый микроконтроллер.

Comment: c озона "Плата Arduino Pro Mini Module ATMEGA328 3.3V 8MHz"

Comment: И в самом деле, есть такая модель.

Comment: сам в шоке, еще видел на 7-12 вольт

Comment: nexoma Благодарю за совет

Comment: дык добавь "комментарий добавляет полезность"  :)

Comment: @nexoma, 7-12 вольт потому, что на плате стоит линейный стабилизатор на 5 вольт. Он сам съедает примерно 2 вольта, поэтому входное напряжение минимум 7, а так как "лишнюю" энергию стабилизатор рассеивает в тепло, то при отсутствии радиатора подавать больше 12 вольт опасно — перегреется.

Comment: @Герман, понятно, что без доп.устройств не обошлось. вариант зачем? для автоэлектроники?

Answer (score 0):

Всем добра. Хочу поделится своим опытом . Делал Wi-Fi сигнализация для дома . Изначально предполагалось , что атмега328 и есп8266 не будут работать друг с другом по UART из за разницы в логических уровнях. Но эксперимент показал совсем иное. Если запитать оба микроконтролера от 3.3 вольтового стабилизатора, то никаких проблем не было выявлено. Схема уже работает месяц и проблем нет.

Comment: Контроллеры Atmega32 делятся на 2 группы. С буквой L в полном названии, и без неё. Те что с буквой L гарантированно работаю на напряжении от 2.7 вольта. Те что без могут работать на напряжении ниже 4.5, а могут и не работать.